# Flutter Google Maps remove navigation button at bottomRight on marker tap

Tags: flutter, marker, google-maps-flutter

Is it possible to remove the google maps navigation button at bottom right when we click on a marker?

[image]

I tried this

```
        Marker(
              consumeTapEvents: true,
              onTap: () {
                print("marker clicked");
              },
              infoWindow: InfoWindow(
                  title: "title",
                  snippet: "snippet",
                  onTap: () {
                    markerTap();
                  }),
                 )
```

It worked but I ran into a new issue that it doesn't open info window on marker on click. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 16):

With google_maps_flutter version 0.5.20 they added support to enable/disable this.

In your GoogleMap widget add:

```
mapToolbarEnabled: false
```