# Add navigation button at bottomRight on marker tap Flutter Google Maps on ios

Tags: flutter, google-maps-flutter

I already have created a flutter android application and works fine. I am using google_maps_flutter plugin to display the map with markers. After when trying to run my app to ios, i encountered a strange problem. It runs as i expected but the bottom right navigation toolbar is not displayed as on android device. I have seen how to disable it only from this question :

> [Flutter Google Maps remove navigation button at bottomRight on marker tap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57180339/flutter-google-maps-remove-navigation-button-at-bottomright-on-marker-tap)

```
Marker(
       markerId: MarkerId('firstMarker'),
       draggable: false,
       icon: BitmapDescriptor.fromBytes(_markerIcon),
       infoWindow: InfoWindow(
          title: f.name,
          snippet: f.time,
          onTap: (){
          displayInfo(f, context);
          }
     ),
     position: LatLng(f.lat, f.lon));
```

Is this caused from flutter or i must do some changes on my source code?

Answer (score 1):

For Android you need to add `mapToolbarEnabled: true` as a property of the `GoogleMap` widget.

Example:

```
GoogleMap(
  mapToolbarEnabled: true,
  buildingsEnabled: true,
  mapType: MapType.normal,
  onMapCreated: (controller) {
    _initMap(controller);
  },
);
```

Comment: /// True if the map should show a toolbar when you interact with the map. **Android only**.
  final bool mapToolbarEnabled;   I still have a problem. Navigation button not showing on iOS.